# Has Globular Homology been studied?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Everyone in taking a course on Algebraic Topology has heard of *singular homology*, the homology theory of topological spaces defined as the composite of functors
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\mathsf{Top} & \longrightarrow & \mathsf{sSet} & \longrightarrow & \mathsf{Ch}_{\Bbb Z} & \longrightarrow & \mathsf{grAb}\\
X & \mapsto & \mathsf{Top}(\Delta^\bullet,X)\\
&& S_\bullet & \mapsto & (\Bbb Z[S_\bullet], \partial_\bullet)\\
&&&& (C_\bullet, c_\bullet) & \mapsto & H_\ast(C_\bullet)
\end{array}$$
Of cause there is no problem with this. In fact from the viewpoint of modelling spaces as things glued from triangles I think simplicial sets (or rather their realizations) can be fairly natural and getting a chain complex from them is somewhat canonical.

On the other hand, a great deal of algebraic topology resolves around spheres and disks, so why don't we define *globular homology* as the „homology theory“ defined as the composite of functors
$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\mathsf{Top} & \longrightarrow & \mathsf{gSet} & \longrightarrow & \mathsf{Ch}_{\Bbb Z} & \longrightarrow & \mathsf{grAb}\\
X & \mapsto & \mathsf{Top}(\Bbb D^\bullet,X)\\
&& S_\bullet & \mapsto & (\Bbb Z[S_\bullet], \partial_\bullet)\\
&&&& (C_\bullet, c_\bullet) & \mapsto & H_\ast(C_\bullet)
\end{array}$$
with $\Bbb D^n = \{x \in \Bbb R^n \mid \Vert x \Vert \leq 1\}$, $\mathsf{gSet}$ denoting the category of [globular sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/globular+set) and $\partial_n = \sigma_n - \tau_n$. By the globular identities this boundary morphisms is welldefined (if I am not mistaken), so we indeed get a chain complex.

> Has this been studied and if so, what is a reference?

To be clear I don't expect to get something "new" from this construction. Maybe it even is hidden in cellular homology, but I am unsure. I simply was unable to find a reference and got curious about it.

As always, thank you very much for your time!

Comment: The answer will be either: it is not actually a homology theory or that it is isomorphic to singular homology. Presumably for your differential you are intending to take some type of alternating sum of n terms. You can then check that when $X$ is a point, the globular homology is trivial in dimensions not 0 and $\mathbb{Z}$ in dimension 0. It is a classic theorem that any homology theory (AKA one satisfying the various excision and functoriality axioms) that takes such values on a point must be isomorphic to singular homology.

Comment: @ConnorMalin You are right, I should start checking the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. But I would prefer not to, assuming there is a working theory of when the composite *nerve - abelianization - chains - homology* actually yields a homology theory…

Comment: Right but the point is that at best it is singular homology so unless you have some reason to believe that this could be easier to compute....

Comment: Well the differentials are easier, but as I said: I don’t really expect to get anything new (which you correctly formalized as the uniqueness of singular homology). It’s solely out of curiosity…

Comment: Well I am not familiar at all with these globes so I can't say much. I do not even see a definition of the realization of a globe so I don't even know how your singular globes are defined.